# How to adjust this css objects with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a feeling this is pretty simple, but my JS is not very good.

I have a div class

```
<div class=" foo1 foo2" style="top: 0px;">
```

I can see in chrome that it this div has an attribute set like this:

```
.foo2
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I'm trying to use JS to adjust the attributes of foo2, but I don't know how to get at it.

```
var changeFoo = document.getElementById ('foo2');
changeFoo.position = "relative";
```

How do I call foo2.position and change it?

Comment: It's a class not an id... See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: Use the `.style` collection: `foo2.style.position = 'relative';`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style

Comment: I was using style, but the div has a style="top: 0px;" parameter, so when I try to change style, It changes element.style, but not .foo2.position

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Its a pure javascript solution.

```
function update_this_css(matchClass) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
    for (i in elems) {
        if((' ' + elems[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + matchClass + ' ')
                > -1) {
            elems[i].style.position = "relative";
        }
    }
}

update_this_css('foo2');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
var foo= document.getElementsByClassName('foo2');   
for(var i=0;i<foo.length;i++){  
foo[i].style.position='relative';  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the JS to identify an element using its ID ('foo2') which you have not set. If you want to use a class name instead you must use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

else you must give your element your desired ID.

Another problem is that you simply have:

```
changeFoo.position
```

where as you need to use:

```
changeFoo.style.position
```

To get your code to work, you need to loop through the results:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) { 
divs[i].style.position='fixed'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I found so far is to use jQuery because regular javascript is so much longer and harder to write. Get a JS library one at jquery.com Learn jQuery once and say thanks to yourself forever :) You can use CSS selectors to get elements without any IDs.

Then use it like this.

```
$('.foo2').css('position', 'relative');
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/